# Lattice barchart - ordering groups

Tags: r, lattice

I have integer-valued categories that I would like to display in ascending order (1,2,3,...,14+). But lattice plots (1,10,11,12,13,14+,2,3,...) how do I fix this?

```
d = data.frame(c1 = rep(data$Weeks, 2),
    c2 = c(rep('Count',14),rep('Fit',14)),
    c3 =c(data$Count,data$Fit))
barchart(c3 ~ c1, groups = c2, d, auto.key=list(x=.9, y=.9, corner=c(1,1)),ylab='', xlab='# of Weeks', main='1910-1919')
```

Comment: Is there any possibility that you integer-valued categories are not really integer, but "character"? And, so, if `barchart` is sorting it, then it gives the output you get.

Comment: @alexis_laz 'typeof' indicates that they are "integer"

Comment: Could you make `d` reproducible? Perhaps after `dput`ing your `d`

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem but with a Trellis plot. You can run this to check the order of your time points (I guess number of weeks):

```
summary(d$c2)
```

Then you can modify it using:

```
d$c2<- factor(d$c2, levels=("1","2","3",...,"14+") #make sure the names are the same what you have in your data.
```

Then you can run the first code and you will see that they are in the right order now.

Answer (score 0):

degopwn's answer is almost there. Do instead

```
d$c2<- factor(d$c2, 
   c("1","2","3",...,"14+") #make sure the names are the same what you have in your data.
```

Test on my data

```
masi@masi:~/Documents$ Rscript plot.associations.r 
           male.Nij      
 Arr/AHB       :32     
 Digoxin arr   :32     
 Furosemide arr:32     
 Sinus         :32      

           male.Nij 
 Sinus         :32   
 Arr/AHB       :32   
 Digoxin arr   :32   
 Furosemide arr:32
```

Example code

```
summary(datm)

datm$male.Nij <- factor(datm$male.Nij, c("Sinus", "Arr/AHB", "Digoxin arr", "Furosemide arr"))

summary(datm)
```